# Public/global range does not seem to be available all the time

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, public, worksheet

I want to have the worksheet run a macro when specific cells are changed.

I have used the code below to initialise the range that determines which cells will cause the macro to be run, but it seems that the lifetime of this range is not of the application?

```
Public ChangeCellList As Range

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Sheets("Program")
    For i = 7 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "E")) Then
            If ChangeCellList Is Nothing Then
                Set ChangeCellList = .Range("E" & i)
            Else
                Set ChangeCellList = Union(ChangeCellList, .Range("E" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Possible problems I would be grateful for advice on:

1) Correct place to declare public variable (eg module1/this workbook/sheet1?)

2) I presume it is a bad idea, but would it kill performance too much if I just initialised this range in Worksheet_Change() sub?

This is the code where the error occurs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Fill As Long
Dim StartWeek As Integer
Dim Duration As Integer

'***Error due to ChangeCellList is nothing***
If Not Application.Intersect(ChangeCellList, Range(Target.Address)) _
 Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Program")
        Fill = Sheets("macroData").Range("C1").Interior.Color

        StartWeek = InputBox("Please enter the Start Week of this Activity", "Start Week")
        Duration = InputBox("Please Enter the Duration of this Activity", "Duration")

        StartCol = StartWeek + 9

        For k = 0 To Duration - 1
            .Cells(Target.Row, StartCol + k).Value = 1
            .Cells(Target.Row, StartCol + k).Interior.Color = Fill
            .Cells(Target.Row, StartCol + k).Font.Color = Fill
        Next k
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `Range(Target.Address)` is the exact same thing as `Target`.

Comment: @Comintern ok, thanks.

Comment: Also not likely to fix the issue, but you need to qualify the `Rows.Count` with the sheet. Just add a `.` before in `.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` to link it to the "Program" sheet. Otherwise, `Rows.Count` will be calculated from whatever the active sheet is.  Also, after the workbook is open, in the Immediate Window (press `CTRL+G` in the VBA editor), type `?ChangeCellList.Address`. I would expect it to return the global variable. That will at least help determine if it's being stored outside that `Workbook Open` sub.

Comment: @BruceWayne ah yes, I hadn't spotted that typo. actually it doesn't normally have an effect as the Program sheet is the only active sheet, but I guess it is better to have more robust code.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with `F8`? Put a "Stop" block at the first line in the `Open` event and press `F8` to walk through it and you should be able to see if/when `ChangeCellList` is getting set.  Are you positive it's being set properly in the `Open` event? Also, why try and get the range when the book opens, instead of during the `Worksheet Change`? Is it because the data may change, and you want to be sure to grab the range before anyone adds/deletes anything?

Comment: @BruceWayne What I have found is that it does seem to be being stored as a global variable, but having the function in the `workbook_open() ` sub does not seem to initialise it when the workbook is opened? For instance I have tried having it in the `worksheet_activate()` sub and when it throws an error you can switch sheets and then it works perfectly for a while until the next time it fails ?

Comment: @BruceWayne  I have stepped through it, and it works if you are sure it has been set (for example if you step through it and then after try and change a cell in that range). but it does not seem to last while the application is still open, if somehow it gets deleted from memory - but nothing else interacts with it (except the worksheet_change sub and the open_workbook sub obviously)

Comment: Try putting it in a regular module.